# ado.net ExecuteNonQuery cause parameter null exception if parameter is not null

Tags: c#, entity-framework, stored-procedures, sqlanywhere, executenonquery

**EDIT** The problem also occures using the entity framework **/EDIT**

Currently i have a mystic problem with ADO.Net and Sybase SQL Anywhere (Version 16.0.0.21584). If i try to write a long varchar over a procedure to the database (around 80MB), `ExecuteNonQuery` throws the exception `The value cannot be NULL` at parameter name `desintation`. The problem is, that no parameter is null and no parameter is named `desintation`. I have written all values to the file system before executing the procedure, to debug the system, all files has a content, so nothing is null here.

One more thing, if i write smaller data to the database, every thing works fine.

The procedure looks like this:

```
ALTER PROCEDURE "admin"."DCS_SQLI_PARM_SetKeyValue"( 
  in @in_lvc_parmName long varchar,
  in @in_bint_workflowID bigint default null,
  in @in_bint_contentID bigint default null,
  in @in_lvc_parm_value long varchar ) 
begin
  declare @bint_id bigint;
  set @bint_id = ISNULL((select ID from DCS_INPUT_Parameter_KeyValue
      where parameter_name = @in_lvc_parmName and ISNULL(ContentID,0) = ISNULL(@in_bint_contentID,0) and WorkflowID = @in_bint_workflowID),
    GET_IDENTITY('DCS_INPUT_Parameter_KeyValue',1));
  insert 

into DCS_INPUT_Parameter_KeyValue
    ( ID,
    parameter_name,
    parameter_value,
    ContentID,
    WorkflowID ) on existing update defaults off values
    ( @bint_id,
    @in_lvc_parmName,
    @in_lvc_parm_value,
    @in_bint_contentID,
    @in_bint_workflowID ) 
end
```

This method is executing the procedure:

```
public static void ExecuteProcedure(string SqlStatement, string ConnectionName, params object[] Parameter)
{
    SAConnection cConnection = DAL.ConnectionManager.GetOpenPoolConnection<SAConnection>(Connection: ConnectionName);

    try
    {
        SACommand cCommand = new SACommand(SqlStatement, cConnection);
        cCommand.CommandType = CommandType.StoredProcedure;

        if (Parameter != null)
        {
            foreach (var cParam in Parameter)
            {
                cCommand.Parameters.Add(new SAParameter() { Value = cParam });
            }
        }

        cCommand.ExecuteNonQuery();
    }
    catch (Exception ex)
    {
        if (UserRightManager.UserHasRightsFrom(0))
        {
            if (System.Environment.UserInteractive)
            {
                MessageBox.Show("SQL-Text: " + SqlStatement + "\r\n" + ex.ToString(), "SQL-Error", MessageBoxButton.OK, MessageBoxImage.Warning);
            }
        }
        else
        {
            if (System.Environment.UserInteractive)
            {
                MessageBox.Show("--- --- --- ---.", "SQL-Fehler", MessageBoxButton.OK, MessageBoxImage.Warning);
            }
        }

        if (cConnection != null)
        {
            if (cConnection.State != ConnectionState.Closed)
            {
                cConnection.Close();
            }
        }

        Base.ExceptionHandling.Write("Error during executing a procedure", Foundation.ExceptionLevel.Error, ex, SqlStatement);

        throw new Exception("Error in ExecuteProcedure", ex);
    }

    cConnection.Close();
}
```

The `ExecuteProcedure` method is very old and must be rewritten, but this should not cause the current problem.

**EDIT**
Using Entity-Framework cause the same error:

```
public void SetParameter(string parameterName, object parameterValue)
{
    try
    {
        //Simplic.PlugIn.DocCenterServer.AS.Core.DB.Database.Instance.ExecuteProcedure("DCS_SQLI_PARM_SetKeyValue", new object[] { parameterName, this.wf.ID, this.ID, parameterValue }); 
        using (FrameworkDbContext dbContext = new FrameworkDbContext())
        {
            // Get Existing id
            var entry = dbContext.DCS_INPUT_Parameter_KeyValue.Where(item => item.Parameter_name == parameterName && item.WorkflowID == this.wf.ID && item.ContentID == this.ID)
                    .FirstOrDefault();

            if (entry == null)
            {
                DCS_INPUT_Parameter_KeyValue value = new DCS_INPUT_Parameter_KeyValue();
                value.Parameter_name = parameterName;
                value.Parameter_value = parameterValue == null ? "" : parameterValue.ToString();


      value.ContentID = this.ID;
                    value.WorkflowID = this.wf.ID;
                    dbContext.DCS_INPUT_Parameter_KeyValue.Add(value);

                    var size = value.Parameter_value.Length;
                    Console.WriteLine("Parameter-Size: " + size.ToString());

                    dbContext.SaveChanges();
                }
                else
                {
                    entry.Parameter_name = parameterName;
                    entry.Parameter_value = parameterValue == null ? null : parameterValue.ToString();
                    dbContext.SaveChanges();
                }
            }
        }
        catch (Exception ex)
        {
            Console.WriteLine(ex.ToString());
        }
    }
```

**EDIT 2**
Switching from `long varchar` to `long binary` seems to solve the problem.

Does any one has an idea what the problem could be?

Thank you.

Comment: Not an answer but, In your C# code, you test:  if (Parameter != null) may not work if only few parameters are null, you may need to write a Linq or loop through each one.

Answer (score 1):

I encounter a similar problem with sybase.
The driver of the database can't handle this kind of parameters. Since a certain size the parameters fail.

To prevent this problem I had to call an update query with the parameter text size set to the max in a temporary table. Then call the stored procedure to take the parameter from the temporary table.

Hope it helps...

[Edit]

```
create table #temp (
  id int identity,
  val text null
);

insert into #temp(val) values(null);
select @@identity;
```

then

```
set textsize 123456 --find the max size
update #temp set val = '[yourlongsizevalue]' where id = @@identity
```

Finally, in your stored procedure

```
select @variable = val from #temp where id = @id
```

For me this worked well. But with entity framework I don't know

Comment: If this works, you will be my hero and saved my from a lot of angry clients :) Thank you!

Comment: Hmm, i have rebuild the procedure with the Entity Framework and get the same error. So the procedure seems not to be the problem here...

Comment: I can't be sure but I think my method works. I update my answer

Comment: And I don't think the stored procedure is the problem. I think it's ADO or the sybase driver that bring this limit in the parameters.

Comment: Ok.. Yes that's weird... Forget what I said. Sorry. I ran on something like long binary are bigger that long varchar...